# Best password reset behavior for missing account

Tags: passwords, forgot-password

I'm wondering what the best behavior is when a user requests a password reset for an email that doesn't exist.

Context: user is not logged in. They just enter an email and hit a reset button.

1. If I tell the user requesting the reset immediately that the account doesn't exist, that's both a bit of security hole and a privacy issue.
2. If I do nothing and it's an innocent mistake (they thought they had an account), they'll be wondering what the heck happened. Most mysterious option, least subject to abuse.
3. I can send an email that says a password reset has been requested but there's no account (and should be ignored blah blah blah). This seems the least noxious but it is a little subject to abuse.

**Update**: On further consideration, I don't really so how **1** is a big deal since they can get the same information by simply trying to sign up/use the same email ... unless I'm missing something ...

Answer (score 2):

I personally would go this way:

1. User enters e-mail address.
2. Screen says "request will be processed, e-mail has been send" or something along those lines.
3. If there is no account linked with this e-mail address: don't send a mail, but don't tell the guy requesting.
4. If there is an account linked with this e-mail: send the reset e-mail including the usual "if this wasn't you simply ignore this mail, if you suspect abuse please contact $foobar"-message.

Here is why i would NOT tell anyone whether an account is linked with this e-mail address: Privacy. If you told everyone, everyone could check if $person is using $service.

Figured i would include why i wouldn't send a mail if there was no such user: Why should i? The user will probably either know which email address he used or try several at once (or only wait a short time span). Of course there are cases in which it would be a bit more userfriendly if one would send those mails, but they aren't important enough to negate the abuse potential.
There is not much abuse potential if only one website does that stuff (as long as they wouldn't send multiple mails in a short timespan), but imagine every webservice going this way. You would just have to collect a few of those services and then emailbomb someone 'you' dislike, without hitting any spamfilter!

Answer (score 0):

Personally, i'm a fan of:

- The user enters an email.
- Whether or not the email exists, say that it has been requested, and if you do not receive an email shortly, try again or contact us.
- In the email, state a password request was submitted, and if it wasn't the user, then to ignore the email.

Also,

- If you're worried about bots scraping your site for emails, add a Captcha.
- If you're worried about people hacking accounts, add a second layer that prompts for a secret question answer.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the third option is the best compromise between user-friendlyness and security. Option 1 seems to be to big of a privacy issue. Using option 2 the user can not know if he has an account, but registered with another email address or if the reset system doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this

- Ask for the username or email
- If that email or username is present, send all the email to the person, with the reset password.

Finished :)